# Kaggle Titanic-Machine Learning From Disaster with TensorFlow: Model Training unable to get loss values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have just started learning Machine Learning with TensorFlow, and I thought it would be a good way to test my poorly underdeveloped skills by entering the *Titanic-Machine Learning from Disaster* on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/). The data for this contest can be found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data).

For simplicity, I dropped all the string values except for `Sex`, which I mapped as `1` for `male` and `0` for `female`.

But during the model training, the loss values of all the epochs are `nan`. I have no idea why this is happening, and if anyone can tell me what's the problem, that would be great.

My Current Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

train_data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
test_data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

train_data['Sex'] = train_data['Sex'].map({'male':1,'female':0})

train_data = train_data.drop('PassengerId', axis=1)
train_data = train_data.drop('Name', axis=1)
train_data = train_data.drop('Ticket', axis=1)
train_data = train_data.drop('Cabin', axis=1)
train_data = train_data.drop('Embarked', axis=1)
train_data = train_data.drop('Fare', axis=1)

test_data = test_data.drop('PassengerId', axis=1)
test_data = test_data.drop('Name', axis=1)
test_data = test_data.drop('Ticket', axis=1)
test_data = test_data.drop('Cabin', axis=1)
test_data = test_data.drop('Embarked', axis=1)
test_data = test_data.drop('Fare', axis=1)

X = train_data.drop('Survived',axis=1).values
y = train_data['Survived'].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.constraints import max_norm

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(x=X_train, 
      y=y_train, 
      epochs=25,
      batch_size=256,
      validation_data=(X_test, y_test), 
      )
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/25
3/3 [==============================] - 1s 102ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 2/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 3/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 4/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 5/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 22ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 6/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 22ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 7/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 8/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 9/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 10/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 11/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 12/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 13/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 14/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 15/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 16/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 17/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 18/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 19/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 20/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 21/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 22/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 23/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 24/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 13ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 25/25
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x18bc9160dc0>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in this dataset the `Age` column have some null values. That's why you get the loss as `nan`.

you can remove the `Age` column or clean the data, to make it without null values.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! When I used train_data.head() to look at it, I couldn't see the complete dataset.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is correction**
it because you forger 1 very important parameter in compile that is metrics parameter.

**Your code**

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

**Correction**

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

you can pass it different type of metrics according to condition that best suit you

Comment: the loss is still nan. afterward, and I am looking for that, but I did get the accuracy. This halfway solved my problem! :D

Comment: I deeply see and observe that your training dataset is containing null values. to handle it you have two options, 1-drop records if there are low amount of null values in column,2-drop column if a column have too much null values,3-replace null values with  temporary values, pandas provide a option for every option. try all the options and select the category that give you best result.

Comment: Will do! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I believe the issue may be caused by `validation_data=(X_test, y_test)`.

I think that the train data needs to be split into three groups to use that option. Perhaps doing this after your initial split and implementing any scaling things to valid set too will help:

```
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.2)
```

and then changing to `validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid)`

Comment: I split it like that right after the original split, then I scaled X_valid with scaler.transform(X_valid), and changed the validation_data to X_valid and y_valid, but It gave the same result.